# Why cant I pass parameter to a call-template in xslt?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am trying to pass a parameter into a  `<xsl:call-template>`,

basically the value of (languageTemp) 
`<xsl:param name="selectedBox">languageTemp</xsl:param>` I want to be passed into

```
<xsl:call-template name="$selectedBox" />
```

But it will not work. It will work when i put it in manually, but my c# application will be passing the parameter from a combobox. So it must be dynamic. Am i misusing the parameter and call-template?

Here is a portion of my XSLT code.

```
<xsl:param name="selectedLanguage">Java</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="selectedUse">Application</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="selectedStandard">ECMA</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="selectedBox">languageTemp</xsl:param>

    <xsl:key name="language-by-use" match="language" use="purpose/intendedUse/@id" />
    <xsl:key name="language-by-standard" match="language" use="standards/standard/@id" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="$selectedBox"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `$` in the template's name? Please show us the input XML you used with the complete XSLT. Neither I can see the parameter in your `xsl:call-template` nor the actual template to be called.

Comment: As in many other languages, you can't put a method or template name into a string variable and then call the template or method dynamically.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, makes sense. So is there a way I can implement the same thing but with an if statement, example. if selectedBox =  languageTemp, call template languageTemp. If selectedBox = standardTemp, call template standardTemp, etc?

Comment: @bjimba sorry but I your solution did not work for me. I will need to call a template during certain conditions, based on the comboBox, unless I'm misunderstanding your updated answer.

Comment: XSLT has `<xsl:choose><xsl:when test="$selectedBox = 'foo'"><xsl:call-template name="t1">...</xsl:call-template></xsl:when><xsl:when test="$selectedBox = 'bar'"><xsl:call-template name="t2">...</xsl:call-template></xsl:when>...</xsl:choose>`. Whether you need that I don't know, calling templates by name is possible but often with XSLT it is the right way to use template matching based on XML input patterns. You might want to show us XML input and the result you want and how input maps to output, then we can might be able to show how to avoid calling templates by name.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I'll try that, and if I can't get it to work correctly, I'll update my solution. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank You It Worked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I will answer my own question. Thanks again, I am new at XSLT and surely is different then other languages.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @MartinHonnen for his advice.

Here is the soultion i used, instead of passing parameters directly to the call-template, i used choose,when statements to call template under certain conditions. it worked with my C# application with passing parameters from the app!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!-- DWXMLSource="lab06.xml" -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >    

    <xsl:param name="selectedLanguage">Java</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="selectedUse">Application</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="selectedStandard">ECMA</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="selectedBox">intendedUseTemp</xsl:param>

    <xsl:key name="language-by-use" match="language" use="purpose/intendedUse/@id" />
    <xsl:key name="language-by-standard" match="language" use="standards/standard/@id" />





    <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$selectedBox = 'languageTemp'">
        <xsl:call-template name="languageTemp" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$selectedBox = 'intendedUseTemp'">
        <xsl:call-template name="intendedUseTemp" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$selectedBox = 'standardTemp'">
        <xsl:call-template name="standardTemp" />
    </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```